# Existance of predual spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I would like to know if there is any Banach space that does not have predual space(obviously incomplete normed linear spaces can not be dual spaces of any normed linear space).

In other words, can there be a normed linear space whose closed unit ball is not weak* compact(Banach-Alaoglu theorem)?

Comment: $L^1(0,1)$, $C([0,1])$, $c_0$ have no predual. This is a consequence of Krein-Milman theorem.